# Dynamically generated table displays '0'

Tags: php, html-table

In PHP I am trying to create a table based off  whats in a database, but I've never created tables before, so I thought I'd leave out the database part of it, and just throw random junk in a for loop, like this:

```
<?php

            $outa='<table border="0"><tr>
                    <th>Month</th>
                    <th>Savings</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>';


        for($i=0;$i<500;$i++)
        {
            $outb = '
                <td>df</td>
                <td>df</td>>';
        }

        $out=$outa+$outb+'
                                    </tr>
                                  </table';

?>
<html>
<head></head><body>
<?php echo $out; ?>
</body></html>
```

But it always ouputs a 0 instead of the table, what gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add strings using dot, e.g. **'string 1' . 'string 2'**, not using **+**.

Comment: Oh my god. I know that! I can't believe I looked past that. I was creating an app in C# lastnight (and you concatenate using +), I guess I just didn't realise what I was doing. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Any may want to look up HEREDOCs (http://php.net/heredoc) as well, for multi-line string building

Answer (score 0):

Your table bracket is not closed appropriately.  Also in php concatenation for string is with . Instead +

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
    for($i=0;$i<500;$i++)
    {
        $outb = '
            <td>df</td>
            <td>df</td>>';
    }
```

just sets `$outb` to the same value 500 times over (and it's invalid HTML!). You use  a `.` to concatenate strings, not a `+` (I hate it. This is why I code web stuff with Python):

```
<?php

  $outa = '<table border="0">
             <tr>
               <th>Month</th>
               <th>Savings</th>
             </tr>

             <tr>';


  for ($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++)
  {
    $outb .= '<td>df</td><td>df</td>';
  }

  $out = $outa + $outb + '</tr></table>';

?>
<html>
<head></head><body>
<?php echo $out; ?>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In php concatenation of two string with `+` will be considered as addition of two integer values. The given string values will be automatically converted as integer. 
`echo ‘st1’ + ‘st2’;` will be converted as `echo 0 + 0;`

Also keep the `<tr>` tag inside the loop:

```
<?php

    $outa='<table border="0"><tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Savings</th>
          </tr>
         ';


for($i=0;$i<500;$i++)
{
    $outb = '<tr>
        <td>df</td>
        <td>df</td></tr>';
}

$out= $outa . $outb . '</table>';


?>


<html>
<head></head><body>
<?php echo $out; ?>
</body></html>
```